# RelativeLayout: Sharing screens height

Tags: android, share, android-relativelayout

Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                >

            <LinearLayout android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:id="@+id/llRow1" />
            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_below="@+id/llRow1"
                          android:id="@+id/llRow2" />
            <LinearLayout android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:id="@+id/llRow3" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

What i wanna have:
- Those 3 "rows" have to share the screens' height
- but with one extra: when i set the 3rd row (llRow3) visibility to GONE, only row1 and row2 have to share the screens height.

How is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a the same `layout_weight` to all of them. So if you'll set visibility of the third one to GONE, they'll still have those weights.
Edit:
Change the ParentLayout to LinearLayout or if you need RelitiveLayout, then you can wrap those three LinearLayout in an other LinearLayout and set weights to them like this:

```
 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llRow2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/llRow1"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llRow3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Layout_weight isnt available in RelativeLayout... :(

Comment: Ah didn't see that you use a RelitiveLayout as your ParentLayout. Can you wrap those three LinearLayout in an other LinearLayout? This could solve this